Radio waves: physical mechanism of ground (surface) wave propagation
Radio waves with frequencies below ~3 MHz can propagate as ground waves, following the curvature of the Earth to reach distances well beyond the visual horizon. However, I am confused about the physical mechanism involved in such ground-wave propagation. I have read two different explantions. The first one can be found e.g. here:

Ground propagation works because lower-frequency waves are more strongly diffracted around obstacles due to their long wavelengths, allowing them to repeatedly bend downward to follow the Earth's curvature.

The second one can be found e.g. here:

Instead of just travelling in a straight line the radio signals tend to follow the curvature of the Earth. This is because currents are induced in the surface of the earth and this action slows down the wave-front in this region, causing the wave-front of the radio communications signal to tilt downwards towards the Earth.

So what is the actual mechanism in play? Diffraction around obstacles such as mountains (or the Earth's curvature itself) or rather induced currents in the surface of the Earth? Or do both things contribute?

The presence of the (curved) surface allows for a range of solutions to Maxwell's equations because of that boundary (and the characteristics of the two media - air and Earth). If you really want to be confused, explore all the various solutions for elastic wave propagation on Earth.

At the interface between air and conductive earth or sea water a special wave solution of Maxwell's equations exists which is bound to this interface and propagates  only along it. The electrical conductivity of the ground (earth/water) is essential for this wave. It is exponentially damped in vertical direction.This wave solution is called a Zenneck wave or Sommerfeld-Zenneck wave, who described it in 1907 and 1909. It is important for the observed long range radio communication in the low and medium frequency range as it is a wave which follows the curvature of earth. Wikipedia, Zenneck wave
It is due to the conductivity of the earth and thus currents induced there. It is not a diffraction phenomenon.

In my own mental picture of this process, it is the slowing-down of the wave front right next to the surface of the earth due to the induced currents, etc. which causes the diffraction of the wave in the first place.
This means that both explanations are talking about the same thing in different ways.
